# Docker proxy logging urls while build

Tags: docker

I am struggling with a problem which is best described on a picture.
I need somehow log all urls requested when I run docker build command.
Can somebody help me how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot monitor the connections called by build command. They are just normal connections pass through your network interface.

You may want to install `tcpdump` and use it to monitor a specific network interface or to filter specific HTTP requests. That is the best what you can do as far as I know.

## UPDATE

If you want to monitor build process which happens inside docker container, you may use `tcpdump` as mentioned above to monitor the network interface of that Docker container using its binding IP address. By that you can see the connections flows in and out that Docker container only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:)